# Split a spark dataframe into multiple frames and write as CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pyspark

I have a use case where in I am reading data from a source into a dataframe, doing a groupBy on a field and essentially breaking that dataframe into an array of dataframes.
My target state is to have all these dataframes be written as individual CSVs files in S3 ( CSV being they need to be downloaded by the client and need to be human readable ).

What's the best way of going about this?
I used this to split df into df_array : `df_array = [(df.where(df[column_name] == i),i) for i in distinct_values]`

And `df.toPandas().to_csv(output_path +'.csv',index=False)` individually on dataframes to convert to CSV files - but the challenges being faced in this approach are

1. My understanding is since I require a single CSV file per my grouping field,  to_csv will bring data from all worker nodes to the driver and and may give driver OOM issue.
2. I am unable to use python multiprocessing to write the individual dataframes to S3 since data is distributed on worker nodes and gives me an error : `Spark: Broadcast variables: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion`
3. No space left on device.

The pipeline is pretty slow as well, what is the better way I can approach this use case?

[EDIT]

I want to control the name of the CSV file which gets created as well. Target state is 1 CSV file per my group-by field ( let's call that Name ) so if there are 10 different Names in my initial df, output will be 10 CSV files each with the title as Name1.csv, Name2.csv and so on

Comment: how big is the said `df` being filtered? you could try to cache it if the size is manageable.

Comment: This is about 1.5 GB,  can you explain a little more about this caching?

Comment: lets say your `df` was created with 10 initial steps. every time you run a loop, the whole lineage is executed. if you [cache](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-cache-and-persist-explained/) the `df` (considering it will fit in memory) the result of `df` is stored internally and the loop will not have to execute the lineage to get the result of `df` for further operations. it is an optimization technique that uses the stored results for further use. the re-execution of the lineage can result in out of memory issues, and caching can overcome that.

Comment: Can you share some document/article on the above concept?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using pyspark, why don't you use the `repartition` and `partitionBy` to achieve your goal?

```
df.repartition(1).write.partitionBy('grouping_field1', 'grouping_field2', ...).save('/path/to/save', format='csv')
```

Comment: I want to control the name of the CSV files I create so that client knows which file to download, from what I understood controlling name of file wouldn't be without the to_csv from Pandas, pls correct me if that's not the case.

Comment: You're correct, as we're using the `repartition` and `partitionby`, the file name must be starting from `part-***` but the directory should be `/path/to/save/grouping_field1=key1/grouping_field2=key2/part-***`. If you must use key value as the file name, I think you should either use your approach `toPandas().to_csv()`, which might be very slow and expensive, or use the the file system renaming command (eg `fs.rename`)

Comment: Follow up question, is there a difference using pandas.to_csv or using the repartition. Obvious advantage of repartition is I no longer depend on 3rd party service and get the functionality within pyspark itself, but apart from this is there any performance/memory advantage of repartitioning vs pandas.to_csv()? My understanding is both will try to bring the distributed data to the driver node then write a single file at the output location.